# Split function into multiple continuous function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I want to know if it is possible and how one can formulate an interval of a function. For example, imagine I have this sin function:

[Sin Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XXFN.png)

Can I formulate aa new function g(x) between [-pi, 0] of the original function f(x) in such a way that g(y) with y belonging to [0, 1] is equal to f(x) with x belonging to [-pi, 0]. I think the term I am looking for is blending functions but I am not sure and I do not have any idea how can I do it.

Comment: I think in this case you need to replace $x$ with a linear expression of $x$. What could be (linear) function that maps $0$ to $-\pi$ and $1$ to $0$?

Comment: @MattiP. Oh I see what you are saying, if I find a linear function that maps the input interval, I take the mapped value and pass it to the sin function just to have the result in the interval I defined! Thanks, but any idea how can I find this function, a simple y = mx + b does the trick?

Comment: Well, I can just give you the function; $f(x) = \pi \times (x-1)$. It's very easy to intuitively see that.

Comment: @MattiP. Thanks man.

Comment: Piecewise-defined function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise.